# Algoritmo para retornar o ponto de intersecção

Tags: java, geometria

Preciso retornar as posições relativas entre duas retas, nesse ponto do programa tenho certeza que são concorrentes. O meu método executa a seguinte equação para evitar o uso de sistemas lineares:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu encontro um lambda e substituo na equação para achar o ponto em comum. Meu problema é: **todos os casos de testes** que escrevi obtive a saída correta **exceto** quando a equação é a seguinte:

r: (x, y, z) = (8, 1, 9) + λ(2, -1, 3)
s: (x, y, z) = (3, -4, 4) + µ(1, -2, 2)

Nesse caso o retorno deve ser o ponto (-2, 6, -6) porém obtenho o ponto (7.6, 1.2, 8.4).

Meu método (Depois que descobri o lambda, eu checo se o valor de lambda deve ser -lambda ou lambda)

```
public Point3D intersectingLines(Line lineOne, Line lineTwo) {
        double x = lineOne.getPoint().getX() - lineTwo.getPoint().getX();
        double y = lineOne.getPoint().getY() - lineTwo.getPoint().getY();
        double z = lineOne.getPoint().getZ() - lineTwo.getPoint().getZ();
        Vector3D pointsDifference = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
        Vector3D second = pointsDifference.crossProduct(lineTwo.getVector());
        Vector3D first = lineOne.getVector().crossProduct(lineTwo.getVector());

        double lambda = first.getNorm() / second.getNorm();
        double xIntersection = lineOne.getPoint().getX() + (lambda * lineOne.getVector().getX());
        double yIntersection = lineOne.getPoint().getY() + (lambda * lineOne.getVector().getY());
        double zIntersection = lineOne.getPoint().getZ() + (lambda * lineOne.getVector().getZ());

        double xInLineTwo = (xIntersection - lineTwo.getPoint().getX()) / lineTwo.getVector().getX();
        double yInLineTwo = (yIntersection - lineTwo.getPoint().getY()) / lineTwo.getVector().getY();
        double zInLineTwo = (zIntersection - lineTwo.getPoint().getZ()) / lineTwo.getVector().getZ();

        if (xInLineTwo == yInLineTwo && xInLineTwo == zInLineTwo) {
            return new Point3D(xIntersection, yIntersection, zIntersection);
        } else {
            xIntersection = lineOne.getPoint().getX() + (-1 * lambda * lineOne.getVector().getX());
            yIntersection = lineOne.getPoint().getY() + (-1 * lambda * lineOne.getVector().getY());
            zIntersection = lineOne.getPoint().getZ() + (-1 * lambda * lineOne.getVector().getZ());

            return new Point3D(xIntersection, yIntersection, zIntersection);
        }
    }
```

Meu teste

```
@Test
    public void testgetRelativePosition_concurrentsTwo() throws Exception{
        Line lineOne = new Line().setPoint(new Point3D(8.0, 1.0, 9.0)).setVector(new Vector3D(2.0, -1.0, 3.0));
        Line lineTwo = new Line().setPoint(new Point3D(3.0, -4.0, 4.0)).setVector(new Vector3D(1.0, -2.0, 2.0));

        Point3D expected = new Point3D(-2.0, 6.0, -6.0);
        Point3D actual = new RelativePositions().intersectingLines(lineOne, lineTwo);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :Point3D [x = -2.0, y = 6.0, z = -6.0]
Actual   :Point3D [x = 7.6, y = 1.2, z = 8.4]
```

Qual o erro no código que não coincide com a fórmula? Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar

[Referência da origem dessa fórmula](https://web.archive.org/web/20180927042445/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62814.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema principal está na fórmula em questão, tanto o teste de mesa e o programa retornavam os mesmos resultados. Essa fórmula está invertida por isso era obtido λ = |5/25| ao invés de λ = |25/5| que é o correto, para todos os outros casos de testes isso não fez diferença.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Outro problema foi notado na minha pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840723/error-in-the-return-of-the-intersection-points?noredirect=1#comment51604320_31840723), é feito uma comparação entre tipos double e que provavelmente será falsa porque não serão exatas:

> I suspect the problem is the line if (xInLineTwo == yInLineTwo &&
>   xInLineTwo == zInLineTwo). Even in the case where this condition
>   should hold, it's unlikely to hold exactly, as these are all double
>   variables, not exact numbers. You should probably apply some kind of
>   tolerance to this condition, for example, Math.abs(xInLineTwo -
>   yInLineTwo) < 0.001 or something of that kind

[Discussão no Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385627/points-of-intersection-of-two-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Daniela, vc poderia modificar seu teste usando as duas linhas seguintes, por gentileza?

obs1: deixar todas coordenadas Z=0 para ficar mais facil de desenhar em um plano (x,y) em vez de um espaco (x,y,z)

obs2: estou fornecendo dois pontos da reta, em vez de um ponto e um vetor, para ficar mais facil ver tambem (so fazer uma conversao'zinha para rodar no seu teste :))

-linha1: ponto inicial **(x=1, y=2)** e ponto final **(x=4, y=4)**

-linha2: ponto inicial **(x=2, y=1)** e ponto final **(x=3, y=5)**

Eu desenhei essas duas linhas em um papel quadriculado, e elas fizeram interseccao no ponto:

(x=3.5 e y=3)

Poderia postar a nova versao de @test quando vc conseguir adaptar para estas novas duas linhas? Desculpe o incomodo, mas eu nao tenho nenhum compilador java neste pc para testar seu codigo, mas posso ajudar por inferencia :) --- eu programo em opengl, entao acho que posso dar uma forcinha :)

Comment: agora vi q achou o resultado. Td bem entao:)